# Error[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to client

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman

I'm facing this weird issue in NodeJS when using with  Express and Mongoose. Basically, I get an error saying "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" even though I don't send more than one header.
Thank you so much in advance! :)

```
router.post('/createReview', verifyAccessToken, async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { userId } = req.payload;
        // businessId=req.body.businessId;

        const { comment, reviewRating, businessId } = req.body;
        const business = await Business.findById(businessId).populate({ path: 'reviews' })
        business.reviews.forEach(async function(review) {
                if (review.customerId.equals(userId)) {
                    // res.redirect('/done')
                    // console.log('sadsa')
                    return res.status(400).send(ResponseObject(400, false, 'You already Reviewed this Business', {}))
                        // return res.json('asdas')
                } else {
                    Review.create({

                        businessId: businessId,
                        customerId: userId,
                        comment,
                        reviewRating


                    }).then(async(result) => {
                        await Business.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: businessId }, { $push: { reviews: result._id } })
                        return res.status(200).send(ResponseObject(200, true, 'Review Created Successfully', {}))

                    })

                }
            })
 } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(ResponseObject(500, false, 'Internal Server Error', { message: err.message }))
    }
})[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Returning within a `forEach` doesn't stop the rest of them from running, so the rest of them will still run after you return the first time.